# Cant delete background image

Tags: image

So my problem is pretty obvious. Add front and side view, tried to move front view picture, it didn't react, so i tried to delete them, side view works as normal, front view picture doesn't react at all.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two separate 3D views, one on the left and one on the right. **Each 3D view has it's own properties panel with its own settings** (including background images). You have the properties panel open for the 3D view on the right, but you are wanting to edit the properties for the 3D view on the left.

Press <kbd>N</kbd> while your cursor is in the *left* 3D view to open its properties panel and remove/change the background images from there.

Comment: So if i have 2 background images or pencil drawing (or something like this), after screen separation i ll have them multiplied? (For example, now i had front and side picture, and after 3d view separation i ll have 4 pictures in my project?)

Comment: When you split a view, any background images in that view will be duplicated but they will be referencing the same images on your computer.